# Conditional INSERT in supabase Postgres RLS

Tags: postgresql, supabase, row-level-security

The premise of my question is simple, I have three tables :

- `users` (user_id)
- `records_users` (record_id, user_id)
- `records` (record_id, created_by)

I would like users to be able to INSERT into the `records_users` table only if their id (column `user_id` from the `users` table) is in the `created_by` field of the records table.

**In other words :** I would like users to only be able to insert rows for which the record_id is an actual record that is tied to them in the record table through the created_by field.

**What I have tried :**

- Have looked through `RLS` options but I cannot seem to find how to integrate a condition based on what is being inserted. Does something like this exist ?

  ```
   CREATE POLICY "Enable insert on linked records"
   ON public.records_users
       FOR INSERT USING (
         record_id_being_inserted IN (SELECT record_id FROM records WHERE created_by                 = auth.uid()) 
       );
  ```
- I have created an RPC Postgres function which applies that logic, but it is blocked by the RLS policies applied to the `records_users` table and I do not wish to open inserts to all users without having this logic mandatory.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your What I have tried section, the example you gave of a RLS, have you tried it? you would change `record_id_being_inserted` to the column name in the `records_users` table.

Comment: Yes, actually you are right. I gave it another shot and referencing the inserted column actually does work simply enough. I think the previous query on which I had tried that had the record_ids confused which caused it not to work initially. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @andrew smith, the answer was pretty straight forward. You can simply reference the fields inserted by using their column names. So for example :

```
 CREATE POLICY "Enable insert on linked records"
  ON public.records_users
      FOR INSERT USING (
   record_id_being_inserted IN (SELECT record_id FROM records WHERE created_by                 = auth.uid()) 
 );
```

This query would work if `record_id_being_inserted` is the name of the column field you want to check.